# Composer package installation fails in some directories

Tags: php, composer-php, monolog, packagist

I would like to install package from http://packagist.org for example `Monolog`. I open `cmd.exe`, go to folder and type `composer require monolog/monolog`

1. When I try executing command in `D:\user` (no Polish characters) composer installs package.
2. When I try executing command in `D:\użyt` (with Polish characters) it fails.

Why does it fail in the second case? Is it OS fault? How can I fix it?